# 1052 - Column 'typeid' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1052

```
select id,pubdate, typeid,aid,jobname,jobdepart,jobplace,jobnumber,jobcontact from
  archives right join jobrt on id=aid where typeid=19
```

1, table  archives have fileds: id,pubdate,typeid...

2, table jobrt have fields:aid,jobname,jobdepart,jobplace,jobnumber,jobcontact, typeid..

3, id=aid

now, i want to select out the id column the jobname,jobplace comlumns when typeid=19,..

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since two tables: `archives` and `jobrt` contains columnName `typeID`, you need to specify the tableName where the value came from, eg

```
SELECT    id
        , pubdate
        , jobrt.typeid
        , aid
        , jobname
        , jobdepart
        , jobplace
        , jobnumber
        , jobcontact
FROM    archives
        RIGHT JOIN jobrt
            ON archives.id = jobrt.aid
WHERE   jobrt.typeid = 19
```

Answer (score 0):

You should identify what table in the select, something like the following:

```
select archives.id,archives.pubdate, archives.typeid,aid,jobname,jobdepart,jobplace,jobnumber,jobcontact from
  archives right join jobrt on id=aid where typeid=19
```